# how to save database for use in jsp web app

Tags: database, jsp, web, pgadmin

I'm trying to create my first very simple web app. I created my database in pgadmin but I don't know how to save it so I can perform basic sql operations such as INSERT, DELETE, ADD, etc through my web app. Please help me.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should perform DB operation on server side Java code i.e. Servlet. So JSP will just take user request and pass it to the corresponding Servlet. And then Servlet can take appropriate action of communicating with DB through JDBC code (or you can also use ORM tools like Hibernate)